# Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am trying to import three.js. I am following the documentation, however I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “three”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”
```

My import statements:

```
<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.139.2/build/three.module.js"
    }
  }
</script>

<script type="module">

  import * as THREE from 'three';
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

</script>
```

Am I importing it wrong? Where would I put the “./”, “../” or “/”?

Comment: What line is returning this error? `import * as THREE from 'three'`? If so, try changing it to `import * as THREE from './three'`

Comment: Are you using a browser that supports import maps? https://caniuse.com/import-maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like you're overcomplicating things with the import maps, and you're introducing the risk of [very poor browser support](https://caniuse.com/import-maps), as brought up by TheJim01.

Just copy the three.module.js file from https://unpkg.com/three@0.139.2/build/three.module.js to a local folder in your app like `/libraries/three.module.js`.

Then import it with

```html
<script type="module">

  import * as THREE from './libraries/three.module.js';
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

</script>
```

Comment: Yup this worked, I was simply using import maps because that what the documentation said.